# HTML5 Regex Pattern Validation

Tags: regex, html

The validation I need is the following
`A-Z, a-z, 0-9`, no trailing/leading whitespace, `-._` only once non-trailing/leading

Till now I have the following:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\S[a-zA-Z0-9]*\S$">
```

This takes care of the leading trailing whitespace and A-Z,a-z,0-9, but it needs minimum 2 characters

Then I thought of something like this for the symbols `-._`

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\S[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\-_+]{,1}\S$">
```

But no luck there. Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide some examples for valid and invalid matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pattern` attribute uses the same syntax as JavaScript, you can use the following regex:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(?=..)[a-zA-Z0-9]*([_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$">
```

<sup>You can test with the snippet above by typing something in, then change focus from the input.</sup>

The input can only contain `a-zA-Z0-9` and **at most** once of `_.-`. The look-ahead in front `(?=..)` checks that there are at least 2 characters.